# How to exchange the svn log into a xml/txt file

Tags: java, svn

When i run "svn log ....... --xml", it just also dislpay in the console.

Is there a way and how to copy that log in other xml/txt file?

Because then i want use java to put those data in database.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the SVN Kit Library - http://svnkit.com/. It gives you a programmatic way to perform SVN operations.

If you just want to store that in a file, you can redirect the output to a file like this

```
svn log --xml > log.xml
```